RCNN RESNET 50 MODEL - my food repo TRAIN
Can I ask for help?
I found this scientific article:
https://www.frontiersin.org/journals/nutrition/articles/10.3389/fnut.2022.875143/full
In which there is a link to a repository with models trained on the COCO dataset.
I would like to train one of these models (mask r-CNN ResNet50) on the MyFoodRepo dataset. I want to work in Google Colab pro with GPU (I don't have the possibility locally), but there is a big problem with library compatibility (Colab has CUDA 12.2). I have tried many ways and so far I have not found a solution. Maybe someone has an idea? 
https://gitlab.aicrowd.com/.../myfoodrepo-experiments/
There are so many issues with mmdetetection:(

You need to ask a clear question with details, not vague description of a problem.
